# Electric guitar with headphones, what equipment do I need?

Tags: electric-guitar

I would like to be able to play an electric guitar using headphones and while following a play along on my laptop. Condo living and a beginner-what kind of interface would I need to make this happen?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

(Not sure it worth an answer, but a bit long for comment)

Any sound card with direct monitoring would do. If you connect it to the PC, you'll get the sound from the play along and the sound of your guitar. Level between your sound and the play along can be adjusted by the amount of direct monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to go is to use a guitar headphone amp (like the Vox Amplug series) or a standalone amp simulator (like the Line6 Pocket Pod) that has an Aux in. Connect that to the output jack of your PC, plug your headphone into the amp.

Comment: I like the Vox because it fits  in the case and you don't have to wait for it to boot up.  And it has an Aux port for your other device

Comment: Any cons to using a focus rite Scarlett?

Comment: A Scarlett would probably work, but a direct plugin like the VOX is simple and cheap.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: if you want your electric guitar to sound like an electric guitar (that is, not just clean sounds), just plugging it into an audio interface isn't enough. That means that you either go through some pedals before going into the interface, or you don't use the direct monitoring, and instead use some software amp simulator on your computer. (Which may or may not introduce latency, i.e., a delay between the time you strike a note and the time you hear it.)